# Import image from external url

Tags: import, image

I want to import a image to product.

I have:

```
$url = 'www.example.com/imagen01.jpg';
$product->addImageToMediaGallery($url, array('image','thumbnail','small'),false,false);
```

But it doesn't work. How can I do that? Do I need to download the image to /media??

Comment: download the image to the /media/import/ folder

Answer (score 0):

Hello Please use below code

```
$imgUrl = 'www.example.com/imagen01.jpg';
$imgName = $this->getImages(imgUrl);

setMediaGallery(array('images' => array(), 'values' => array()))
            ->addImageToMediaGallery('media/import/'.$imgName, array('image', 'thumbnail', 'small_image'), false, false);


public function getImages($imgUrl) {
    $thumbnail = $imgUrl;

    $newfilename = 'image name here with file extension';

    $fullpath = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'import' . DS . $newfilename;

    try {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $thumbnail);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);
        $rawdata = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        if (file_exists($fullpath)) {
        unlink($fullpath);
        }
        $fp = fopen($fullpath, 'x');
        fwrite($fp, $rawdata);
        fclose($fp);
    } catch (Exception $e) {

    }
    return $newfilename;
    }
```

Comment: get complete image info using this function pathinfo($thumbnail);